# safari not scrolling when the child element is over the parent

Tags: css, firefox, safari

I have tab sections. When clicking on tab, its child content comes over the sections with CSS

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 9999;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 250px;
overflow: scroll;
```

but it seems the child element isn't scrollable.

Answer (score 1):

Please mention the Overflow-x or y axis and don`t use overflow:scroll; use overflow:hidden;

```css
.abc {
height:100px;
overflow-x:hidden;}
```

```html
<div class="abc">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```

Comment: Yes but in my case, there is another solution, as is doesn't help

Comment: @TakhtakTeam please share your code on codepen editor

Comment: thanks. I tried to create a snippet but my code works on codepen